# how to merge lines that do not begin with certain character

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, tr

if i have the following:

```
>A13P0
ACCATAGAGAG
CCCGAGATTTA
>03HK2
ACACAGTGTGT
TTAGAGGGAGA
```

How do I merge lines that do not begin with `>`?

i.e.

```
>A13P0
ACCATAGAGAGCCCGAGATTTA
>03HK2
ACACAGTGTGTTTAGAGGGAGA
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
perl -ne'
   if (/^>/) {
      print("\n") if $. != 1;
   } else {
      chomp;
   }
   print;
} {
   print("\n") if $. != 1;
'
```

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924) for usage.

Comment: Maybe you should precise that this is Perl.

Comment: @Ed Morton, Replacing `chomp;` with `s/\s+\z//;` will cause it accept both CRLF and LF.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been asked/answered a thousand times but I can't find it so:

```
$ awk '/^>/{print (NR>1?ORS:"") $0; next} {printf "%s", $0} END{print ""}' file
>A13P0
ACCATAGAGAGCCCGAGATTTA
>03HK2
ACACAGTGTGTTTAGAGGGAGA
```

Answer (score 2):

with a perl command line:

```
perl -pE '$.>1 && !s/^>/\n>/ && chomp; END{say}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed :

```
$ sed ':a;$!N;/>/!{s/\n\([^>]\)/\1/;ta};P;D' file
>A13P0
ACCATAGAGAGCCCGAGATTTA
>03HK2
ACACAGTGTGTTTAGAGGGAGA
```