# Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner

Tags: perl

I was given a Perl one-liner. It has the following form:

```
perl -pe'...'
```

How do I specify the file to process to the program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation on how to launch `perl` is found in the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) man page.

```sh
perl -pe'...' -i~ file [file [...]]   # Modifies named file(s) in place with backup.
perl -pe'...' -i file [file [...]]    # Modifies named file(s) in place without backup.
perl -pe'...' file.in >file.out       # Reads from named file(s), outputs to STDOUT.
perl -pe'...' <file.in >file.out      # Reads from STDIN, outputs to STDOUT.
```

If the file's name could start with a `-`, you can use `--`.

```sh
perl -pe'...' [-i[~]] -- "$file" [...]
```

If you wanted to modify multiple files, you could use any of the following:

```sh
find ... -exec               perl -pe'...' -i~ {} +   # GNU find required
find ...         | xargs -r  perl -pe'...' -i~        # Doesn't support newlines in names
find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 perl -pe'...' -i~
```

In all of the above, square brackets (`[]`) denote something optional. They should not appear in the actual command. On the other hand, the `{}` in the `-exec` clause should appear as-is.

---

Note: Some one-liners use `-n` and explicit prints instead of `-p`. All of the above applies to these as well.

Comment: This is very useful. Can you also add how to use perl in -exec option of find command.

Comment: @stack0114106, It's already there. It's the first one.

Comment: Thank you.. I thought that requires a for loop.

Comment: @stack0114106, Perl's `-n`/`-p` will happily read from each file provided on the command line in turn. All three version can pass multiple files to a single invocation of `perl`. Use `-exec perl ... \;` (GNU `find` or otherwise) to get only one file per invocation of `perl` (e.g. if you want to do something on a per-file basis in `END{}`.)