# convert row to column based on text

Tags: perl, awk

I have a rather large file (single column) with data similar to this:

```
BT1111
2.2.2.2/3
3.3.3.3/4
7.2.1.1/5
BT6766
2.2.1.1/5
4.5.1.1/7
BT9898
4.4.4.4/2
8.8.8.8/9
```

I wish to find a function that can align it into two columns, by moving all entries starting with digit one column (`$1` to `$2`) and enrich it with the corresponding BT field, so desired output should be

```
BT1111;2.2.2.2/3
BT1111;3.3.3.3/4
BT1111;7.2.1.1/5
BT6766;2.2.1.1/5
BT6766;4.5.1.1/7
BT9898;4.4.4.4/2
BT9898;8.8.8.8/9
```

I can't imagine how to ensure the "look for next occurence" should be performed, but hope there is a function for it I have managed to overlook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/BT/{a=$1; next}{print a ";" $1}' input.txt
BT1111;2.2.2.2/3
BT1111;3.3.3.3/4
BT1111;7.2.1.1/5
BT6766;2.2.1.1/5
BT6766;4.5.1.1/7
BT9898;4.4.4.4/2
BT9898;8.8.8.8/9
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! - by parsing it I realized that I had been overlooking lineshifts that caused a mess - upon getting rid of these this simple solution was just what I dreamed for.

Comment: As per the original question, the criterion is *"all entries starting with digit"*, not "entries not starting 'BT'".

Comment: `..and enrich it with the corresponding BT field.` The input OP provides is clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -nle'if (/^\D/) { $n=$_ } else { print "$n;$_" }' input.txt
```

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924) for alternate usages.