# Delete newline character in text file if next line is less than a certain length

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I'd like to create a script with any combination of bash, sed, awk, or perl that deletes the newline character of a line if the next line is less than a certain length.  Let's say we want to delete the newline character if the next line is less than 5 characters.  If we have this source text file:

```
hi hi hi hi hi
bye
fun fun fun fun fun
batman
shirt shirt shirt
pants pants pants
belt
paper paper paper
```

Here's the desired output:

```
hi hi hi hi hibye
fun fun fun fun fun
batman
shirt shirt shirt
pants pants pantsbelt
paper paper paper
```

Here's a script that identifies all the lines that are less than 5 characters:

```
cat source.txt | awk 'length($0) < 5 { print NR }'
```

It returns this.

```
2
7
```

Here's a script that gets rid of the newlines (it's the line numbers from the previous script minus one):

```
perl -pe 'chomp if $.==1||$.==6' source.txt
```

How do I combine these two scripts?  Or is there a better way to solve this?

**Update**

There were multiple correct answers (some didn't work on my Mac, but I think they'd work on other machines).  Here's how long the correct answers took on my machine with a 769,811 line CSV file (40,000 lines had the newline character removed).

- Ed Morton's awk solution: 23.7 seconds
- wolfrevokcats perl with slurp: 4.5 seconds
- John1024's solution didn't work on my Mac (but think it works on other OSs)
- ikegami's perl without slurp: Killed the task after 7 minutes

Comment: Please specify what should happen if `printf '%s\n'foobar a b c d  > source.txt`.  That is, should the output be the equivalent of `printf "%s\n" foobara bc d`, or `printf "%s\n" foobarabcd`, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -p0777e "s{\r?\n(?=.{0,5}$)}{}mg" test.txt
```

**output**

```
hi hi hi hi hibye
fun fun fun fun fun
batman
shirt shirt shirt
pants pants pantsbelt
paper paper paper
```

[ Well it took me 2 minutes to write the one-liner and about an hour to explain. ]

Here's the explanation:

**Switches:**

`-p` - read every line of the input files, run the code specified by `-e` for each line, and print the variable `$_` (which is modified by the `-e` code)

`-0[octal number]` - input line separator; if we specify 0777 the whole file will be considered a line and read at once

`-l` - strip input lines from ending `\n`, set the `output line separator` equal to the `input line separator`. (I removed it, cause it's actually not needed here)

**Now the regular expression:**

```
s{\r?\n(?=.{0,5}$)}{}mg
```

`s{pattern}{replacement}` - search for `pattern` in variable `$_` and replace it with `replacement`

pattern parts:

`\r?\n` - match every newline symbol. For Unix `\n` would be enough, `\r?` - optional match of CR that may be necessary for old perl versions under Windows.   Actually I think `\r?` can be removed too.

`(?=pattern)` - a positive look-ahead match of `pattern`, a zero width match, that is it does not consume the characters.

`.{0,5}$` - match from zero to five characters ending with

`s{}{}` operator modifiers: `m` - multiline matching, makes `$` match *just before* `\n` everywhere in text, not only at the end of the line. 
`g` - global matching, replace every occurrence in the text.

**Finally, how it all works:**

Perl slurps the whole file (`-0777`) and (`-p`), then it searches for every occurence of `\r?\n` that is followed by no more than 5 non-newline characters and a newline: `(?=.{0,5}$)`.
Every occurrence is replaced by the empty string `{}`.

I think I've been clear enough.

Additional information can be obtained from: `perldoc perlre`, `perldoc perlop` , `perldoc perlrun`.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Can you add a little explanation?

Comment: You have it backwards. `\r?\n` is only useful on unix (to handle both unix and Windows files). `\n` will handle both unix and Windows files on Windows.

Comment: When I was writing about old versions of perl for Windows I actually meant cygwin perl, I just didn't recall that at once. I used cygwin perl quite a long ago, so that's where it came from. And I've just checked: cygwin based perl still has that quirk.

Answer (score 4):

As in life, in software it's much easier to do things based on what has happened rather than what will happen. Don't think of any problem has needing to do X if the NEXT line contains Y, think of it as needing to do Z if the CURRENT line contains Y and then the solution is always simple and obvious, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1{ printf "%s%s", prev, (length() < 5 ? "" : ORS) }
{ prev = $0 }
END{ print prev }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
hi hi hi hi hibye
fun fun fun fun fun
batman
shirt shirt shirt
pants pants pantsbelt
paper paper paper
```

In the above we print a newline if the CURRENT line length is 5 or more. It's clear and simple and will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Comment: I completely agree with your intro, but I wonder if it is better captured with `{printf "%s%s", (length >= 5 ? sep : ""), $0; sep = ORS}END{printf "%s",sep}` :) Or even `length >= 5 { printf "%s", sep } { printf "%s", $0; sep = ORS; } END { printf "%s", sep }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid slurping and you want to look ahead, the general solution is to buffer as many lines as you want to look ahead. One in this case.

```
perl -ne'
   chomp;
   if (length >= 5) {
      print "$buf\n";
   } else {
      print $buf;
   }

   $buf .= $_;

   END { print "$buf\n" if defined $buf; }
'
```

In this particular case, you can make do with the following:

```
perl -pe'chomp; print "\n" if length >= 5 && $. > 1; END { print "\n" if $. }'
```

Both of these solutions handle inputs that don't have a line feed on the last line.

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is also good for simple substitutions such as this:

```
$ sed -E ':a; N; s/\n(.{,4})$/\1/; ba' source
hi hi hi hi hibye
fun fun fun fun fun
batman
shirt shirt shirt
pants pants pantsbelt
paper paper paper
```

How it works:

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `N`

  This reads in the next line and appends it (with a newline character) to the current contents of the pattern space.
- `s/\n(.{,4})$/\1/`

  If a newline character occurs within 4 characters before the end of the current line, then remove the newline
- `ba`

  If the above substitution command resulted in a change to the line, then jump back to label `a`.

#### BSD/MacOs

The above was tested with GNU sed.  For BSD/macOS sed, try:

```
sed -E -e :a -e N -e 's/\n(.{,4})$/\1/' -e ba source
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work on my machine (I'm on a Mac).  It just prints out the same text file that was input without removing any newlines.

Comment: @Powers Sorry about that.  It works for me on Linux.  I just added to the end of the answer code that I expect will work on a Mac.

Comment: The OP says ` delete the newline character if the next line is *less* than 5 characters`.

Comment: @potong Good eye!  I just updated the answer for _less_ than 5 characters.

Comment: By swapping the `ba` for `ta` and adding `P;D` the sed script could change from slurping the file to reading no more than 2 lines at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed (ok on OpenBSD)

```
sed -e '$b' -e 'N;/\n...../{P;D' -e '};y/\n/ /;s/ \([^ ]*$\)/\1/' infile
```