# Remove multiple duplicate lines from a file

Tags: perl, duplicates

I have a Perl script run in crontab that generates a file rich with duplicate entries, because on each run it rewrites information previously written.

I would use a `sort -u` of file, but, I would do it at the end of the Perl script file.

#### My list

```
10/10/2017 00:01:39:000;Sagitter
10/11/2017 00:00:01:002;Lupus
10/12/2017 00:03:14:109;Leon
10/12/2017 00:09:00:459;Sagitter
10/13/2017 01:11:03:009;Lupus
12/13/2017 04:29:00:609;Ariet
10/11/2017 00:00:01:002;Lupus
10/12/2017 00:03:14:109;Leon
...
```

#### My code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Libraries
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

%lines = ();

# Remove duplicate

open( TMP_GL_OUTPUT, '>', $OUTPUT_FILE ) or die $!;

while ( <TMP_GL_OUTPUT> ) {
    $lines{$_}++;
}

open( OUTFILE, '>', $TMPOUTPUT_FILE ) or die $!;
print OUTFILE keys %lines;
close( OUTFILE );

close( TMP_GL_OUTPUT );
```

Where am I going wrong? In shell it feels shorter than in Perl.

```
sort -u $TMPOUTPUT_FILE > $OUTPUT_FILE
```

As Suggested by ikegamy user, I've do as following:

```
move $OUTPUT_FILE, $TMPOUTPUT_FILE; # Copy file
run [ 'sort', '-u', '--', $TMPOUTPUT_FILE ], '>', $OUTPUT_FILE; # Remove duplicate
unlink $TMPOUTPUT_FILE;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile (`$OUTPUT_FILE`, `$TMPOUTPUT_FILE` and `%lines` undeclared), and you try to read from a file opened for output (you used `>` in the first open).

Comment: First, you are opening `TMP_GL_OUTPUT` to write, not read.

Comment: @Dada thanks for your support, I've use command of ikegami to solve this problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are asking why your Perl program is longer than your shell script.

First of all, your shell script does something completely different than your Perl program.

- Your shell script executes a program, and stores its out in a file.
- Your Perl program reads a file, manipulates the data it read, and stores the output in a file.

The Perl equivalent to

```
sort -u -- "$TMPOUTPUT_FILE" > "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

is

```
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ 'sort', '-u', '--', $TMPOUTPUT_FILE ], '>', $OUTPUT_FILE;
```

(There are differences in error handling between these two.)

They're not that different in length.

This brings up the second difference. The shell specializes in executing programs, but Perl is a general purpose language. It would be surprising if it wasn't longer in Perl!

(Now try comparing the size of your Perl program to the source of `sort`...)

Comment: huh??? I didn't post a solution to anything. I just answered a question about language differences. This post should not be taken as an endorsement for executing the `sort` utility. (There are reasons for which it's a good idea, and there are reasons for which it's not.)

Answer (score 1):

List::Util is a core module.

```
use List::Util 'uniq';

print for uniq <>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost OK.

My proposition is only to `chomp` each line, before you
save an element in the hash.

The reason is that e.g. the last line, not terminated
with a `\n` may look just the same as one of previous lines,
but without `chomp` the previous line would have contained
the terminating `\n`, whereas the last - not.

The resut is that both these lines will be **different** keys in the hash.

Compare my example program (working, presented below) with yours, there are
no other significant differences, apart from reading from `__DATA__` and
writing to the console.

In my program, for demonstration purposes, I put 2 variants of printout,
one with key values (repetition counts) and another, printing just keys.
In your program leave only the second printout.

```
use strict; use warnings; use feature qw(say);

my %lines;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    $lines{$_}++;
}
while(my($key, $val) = each %lines) {
    printf "%-32s / %d\n", $key, $val;
}
say '========';
foreach my $key (keys %lines) {
    say $key;
}
__DATA__
10/10/2017 00:01:39:000;Sagitter
10/11/2017 00:00:01:002;Lupus
10/12/2017 00:03:14:109;Leon
10/12/2017 00:09:00:459;Sagitter
10/13/2017 01:11:03:009;Lupus
12/13/2017 04:29:00:609;Ariet
10/11/2017 00:00:01:002;Lupus
10/12/2017 00:03:14:109;Leon
```

### Edit

Your code assigns no names to `$OUTPUT_FILE` and `$TMPOUTPUT_FILE`,
you even didn't declare these variables, but I assume, that in your actual
code you did it.

Another detail is that `%lines` should be preceded with `my`,
otherwise, as you put `use strict;` the compiler prints an error.

### Edit 2

There is a quicker and shorter solution than yours.

Instead of writing lines to a hash and printing them as late as in
the second step, you can do it in a **single** loop:

- Read the line.
- Check whether the hash already contains a key equal to the line just read.
- If not, then:

  - write the line to the hash, to block the printout, if just the
    same line occured again,
  - print the line.

You can even write this program as a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne"print if !$lines{$_}++" input.txt
```

If you run the above command from the Windows `cmd`, it will print the output
to the console. If you use Linux, instead of double quotes, you can use apostrophes.

You may of course redirect the output to any file, adding `> output.txt` to
the above command.

The code is executed for each input line, chomped due to `-l` option.

If any other details concerning Perl one-liners are not known to you, search the web.

Comment: There's no need to empty a new hash, and so no need for the `BEGIN` block in your one-liner. It also won't work on a Linux platform because you need single quotes around the parameter to `-e`. This `perl -lne 'print unless $lines{$_}++' input.txt` will work fine.

Comment: Re "*You may of course redirect the output to any file*",  See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742890/specifying-file-to-process-to-perl-one-liner)