# How to sort complicated strings in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, sorting, awk

I have to sort cell names like this (no matters if it comes from a file or a variable): expected result

```
BAR.A1
BAR.A1-1
BAR.A2
BAR.A3
BAR.A10
FOO.A1
FOO.B1
FOO.B1-1
```

What I tried results in this wrong order :

```
BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
FOO.A1
FOO.A10 <--- wrong place
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
```

I tried many combinaisons of

```
sort -n
sort -h
sort -d
```

none works.

Any clue ?

Comment: You've given an example of one output you're getting with a field in the wrong spot, could you please edit the question to show the output you would like to see?

Comment: The expected one is the first list. Please edit if you have enough reputation points (I don't)

Comment: You want `FOO` sorted before `BAR` then?

Comment: So you want descending order before the dot and ascending alphabetical+ numerical order after the dot? Is the format always three chars, one dot, one letter, then some numbers or hyphens?

Comment: Aahh sorry, BAR shoud be before FOO :/ Please if someone can edit. This is just a sample

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want to sort by field 1 alphabetically, then field 2 version-wise

```
sort -t. -k 1,1 -k2,2V <<END
FOO.A1
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
FOO.A10
BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
END
```

```
BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
FOO.A1
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
FOO.A10
```

Answer (score 1):

There are still various unclear points (you are not saying exactly the output you want) but `sort -g` should do it:

```
$ cat s.txt
FOO.A1
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
FOO.A10
BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
$ sort -g s.txt
BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
FOO.A1
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A10
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
```

`-g` is defined as such:

> -g, --general-numeric-sort, --sort=general-numeric
>                Sort by general numerical value.  As opposed to -n, this option handles general floating points.  It has a more permissive format than that allowed by -n but it has a significant performance drawback.

But `-n` would fit here as well, so your desired output is not clear.

Based on your further updates, maybe this is what you want:

```
$ sort -t '.' -k 2 -V < s.txt
BAR.A1
FOO.A1
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
FOO.A10
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
```

Comment: `FOO.A10` should be after `FOO.A3`

Comment: @MévatlavéKraspek see update. your question is very unclear/misleading on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry @Patrick Mevzek for my bad description, not enough reputations points to edit my post by myself.

Comment: Your last command is good, thanks, already accepted another one

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -MSort::Key::Natural=natsort -e'print for natsort <>'
```

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924) for usage.

Answer (score 0):

version sort

```
$ sort -V file

BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
FOO.A1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
FOO.A10
FOO.A1-1
```

**updated** based on clarified question

```
$ sort -t- -k1,1V -k2 file

BAR.A1
BAR.B1
BAR.B1-1
FOO.A1
FOO.A1-1
FOO.A2
FOO.A3
FOO.A10
```

Comment: `FOO.A1-1` should be before `FOO.A10`

Comment: 'like this' means this is what I expect, sorry if it's not clear enough

Comment: @Mévatlavé: You wrote *"I have to sort cell names like this"* which implies that the cell names are "like this", not the way they're sorted. It looks like you're showing the input data.

Comment: @Borodin: sorry for my bad description, but glenn jackman understood what I mean. I liked to edit, but I don't have any reputation points to do so. My appologies