# Search first pattern and search second pattern and then insert a new line above the second pattern

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I got stuck with following text processing in a file, such that -> Search the first pattern and then search second pattern and then insert a new line above the second pattern.

**File Sample:**

```
some text 1
First-search-text some other text
some text 2
some text 3
Second-search-text
```

**Desired output to be replaced in the file:**

```
some text 1
First-search-text some other text
some text 2
some text 3
New line to be inserted
Second-search-text
```

any pointers will be great help with awk or sed.

Answer (score 2):

Set a flag on first match, then search for second match with flag set:

```
 awk '/First-search-text/{f=1}f&&/Second-search-text/{print "New line to be inserted"}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [ed](/questions/tagged/ed)

```
ed file <<'END_OF_COMMANDS'
/First-search-text/
/Second-search-text/
i
New line to be inserted
.
wq
END_OF_COMMANDS
```

Comment: nice, what does that dot `. ` doing? means end of `ed` script or placeholder for previous line containing `Second-search-text`?

Comment: it means "end of text to insert"

Answer (score 2):

Insert before every second-match after a first-match:

```
perl -pe'print "New line\n" if $f && /^Second-search-text/; $f||=/^First-search-text/'
```

Insert before the first second-match after every first-match:

```
perl -pe'print "New line\n" if (/^First-search-text/../^Second-search-text/) =~ /E0/'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^First/,/^Second/!b;/^Second/i New line to be inserted' file
```