# Input and output file in perl terminal

Tags: perl, terminal

Please something wrong in this code, in input and output, i don't know how i can correct this code:

```
echo < in.txt | perl -CS -pe 's/[\x{0830}-\x{\x{9000}]+//g  > out.txt
```

The problem how i can import `in.txt` and export `out.txt`.

In sed it's easy like this

```
sed < in.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: exactly the same, `perl -e'...' < in.txt > out.txt`

Comment: (really, with [command switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) `perl -ne'...'` or `perl -pe'...'` so loop over STDIN is set up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `echo` doesn't read from STDIN.
- You have an unmatched `'`.
- `\x{\x{9000}` should be `\x{9000}`.
- The range of characters you are removing is very peculiar, and surely incorrect.  It starts in the middle of a seemingly arbitrary block, and it includes a huge swath of space that's not just unassigned, but not part of any blocks. I'm unable to fix this without more information.

Fixed:

```
perl -CS -pe's/[\x{0830}-\x{9000}]+//g' <in.txt >out.txt
```

or just

```
perl -CS -pe's/[\x{0830}-\x{9000}]+//g' in.txt >out.txt
```

---

See also: [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)