# Removing the trailing delimiters dynamically

Tags: shell, perl

I am new to scripting and I need to write a script to remove unwanted delimiter from the last line of the flat file which will be changing dynamically.

EG:

```
1|AK|1,asd|CHN|TN|IN|600001
2|AK|1,asd|CHN|TN|IN|600001
AK|10-01-2019|2||||
```

Like this different files are there and row and column will be varying for each file.
So how to remove the trailing pipelines only from the last row (I,e) after 2

Thanks and Regards, 
Aravind Kumar Sekar

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for Perl's [`split()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function says this:

> If LIMIT is omitted (or, equivalently, zero), then it is usually treated as if it were instead negative but with the exception that trailing empty fields are stripped (empty leading fields are always preserved)

So, the default behaviour of `split()` is to remove trailing empty fields. We can then use [`join()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) to regenerate the original record minus any trailing delimiters.

So it can be as simple as:

```
# Note that '|' has a special meaning in regexes, so we
# need to escape it, using '\'.
my $output_line = join '|', split /\|/, $input_line;
```

Or, putting it in a complete program that reads from `STDIN` and writes to `STDOUT`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  say join '|', split /\|/;
}
```

If you put that in a file called `rmtrailing`, then it can be run from a command line like this:

```
$ perl rmtrailing < your_input_file.txt > your_output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will delete the trailing pipes from all lines:

```
perl -ple's/\|+\z//'
```

If you want to leave trailing pipes in place on all but the last line, you can use the following:

```
perl -nle'
   print($prev) if defined($prev);
   $prev = $_;
   END {
      if (defined($prev)) {
         $prev =~ s/\|+\z//;
         print($prev);
      }
   }
'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Answer (score 0):

This sed one-liner will do the job:

```
sed '$s/|*$//' file
```

#### Test:

```
kent$  cat f
a|b
a|b||||||
||||
foo|bar||||||

kent$  sed '$s/|*$//' f
a|b
a|b||||||
||||
foo|bar
```

You see that only the last line was changed.