# how to get all third entries, till they appear in the second column

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file, that is sorted by first column.

```
10,W,A
20,W,E
30,I,W
40,A,E
50,P,E
60,S,A
70,A,P
80,A,I
100,A,S
110,I,S
120,A,N
130,E,N
```

I need to get all the first columns together until when the third column doesn't appear in the second column. If my third column value has already appeared in second column, it should be ignored.

My attempt to bring it using awk is as follows

```
$ awk -F"," ' { f[$2]++; if( !f[$3] ) { d[$3]=$1 }  f[$3]++ } END { for(i in d) print i, d[i] } ' cg.txt
N 120
A 10
E 20
```

what I'm expecting is

```
N 120, 130
A 10
E 20, 40, 50
```

Comment: A comes in 3rd column in the first line itself, so it should be counted.. in 4th line it is there in second column.

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more explicit about the algorithm that gets us from your input file to your required output. Please talk us through it line by line.

Comment: E comes in the third column untill the last line so 20 40 and 50 should be concatenated

Comment: just remove `f[$3]++` and change `d[$3]=$1` with `d[$3]=d[$3]", "$1` or more exactly `if (d[$3]) { d[$3]=d[$3] ", " $1 } else { d[$3]= $1}`

Comment: @stack0114106, but`N` never came in 2nd column why its value in output? Also `I` is not there too, could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: yes, but it is like a corner case and it should be captured till end of the file

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul.. you are right!... pls add it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -F, -lane'
   ++$seen{ $F[1] };
   push @{ $groups{ $F[2] } }, $F[0] if !$seen{ $F[2] };
   END {
      local $" = ", ";
      print "$_ @{ $groups{$_} }" for sort keys %groups;
   }
'
```

- `-F, -a` causes the input line to be split at commas into `@F`.
- We keep track of what values we've seen in the second column using `%seen`.
- If it's a value we haven't seen, add it to the `%groups`, a hash of arrays.
- And the end, print out the hash of arrays. `$"` is used so the array elements are separated by `,␠` instead of the default `␠`.

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. Considering only condition print all of 3rd column values till its first occurrences in 2nd column(tested with samples  provided only)

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  OFS=", "
}
{
  a[$3]=(a[$3]?a[$3] OFS:"")$1
}
{
  ++c[$2]
}
($2 in a) && c[$2]==1{
  print $2 " " a[$2]
}
END{
 for(i in a){
     if(!(i in c)){
         print i" " a[i]
     }
 }
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @stack0114106, Could you please explain more on which part it is not working? As per logic it looked to me working, kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: "I" has appeared already in column 2 in line#3 so it should not be in output

Comment: @stack0114106, oh ok, I didn't know about that condition, could you please check now?

Comment: it misses "N" now

Comment: @stack0114106, Sure fixed it, apologies for this, I thought `N` should be skipped honestly, cheers.

Comment: it works for the given input.. but still needs refining i.e if I remove the last line, it prints ````N 120```` which is correct, but it also prints an additional blank line..

Comment: @stack0114106, ok, do you have blank lines in your Input_files?

Comment: my bad!!...here were some trailing blank lines.. never mind, it is not an issue.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$2]; k=$3} 
       !(k in a) {b[k]=b[k] s[k] $1; s[k]=FS} 
       END       {for(k in b) print k, b[k]}' file

N 120,130
A 10
E 20,40,50
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl code for your data

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
my %data;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @a = split ',';

    push @{$data{$a[2]}}, $a[0] if not $seen{$a[2]};

    $seen{$a[1]} = 1;
}

while( my($k,$v) = each %data ) {
    printf "%s %s\n", $k, join ", ", @$v;
}

__DATA__
10,W,A
20,W,E
30,I,W
40,A,E
50,P,E
60,S,A
70,A,P
80,A,I
100,A,S
110,I,S
120,A,N
130,E,N
```

Answer (score 0):

Added as answer from comment as requested by OP.

Just remove `f[$3]++` and change `d[$3]=$1` with `if (d[$3]) { d[$3]=d[$3] ", " $1 } else { d[$3]= $1}`.