# Change suffix on partial duplicates with bash perl

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I have a file with multiple columns, and some of their names are partial duplicates, following this pattern:

```
[]$head -n1 file.csv

AGE_030 AGE_031 AGE_032 AMET_022 ... MEND_009 MOLI_032 ... OIA_013 SH-1 SH-10 SH-107
SH-108 SH-4 SH-1_new SH-4_new AREN_1 AREN_28 AREN_3 AREN_4 AGE_032_new AMET_022_new
MEND_009_new MOLI_032_new OIA_013_new...
```

All column names with **_new** suffix have another match without it.

I want to replace the suffixes of both mathes in this way for all partial duplicates:

- **AGE_032** to **AGE_032_old**
- **AGE_032_new** to **AGE_032**

I want to do it in a way that allows me to edit the column names INSIDE the file, as `perl -i` does.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to add `_old` if there's no duplicate?

Comment: No, only to the ones with duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -pale'
   next if $. != 1;

   my %map = map { /^(.*)_new\z/s ? ( $1 => "$1_old", $_ => $1 ) : () } @F;
   @F = map { $map{$_} // $_ } @F;
   $_ = "@F";
'
```

If the line is `AGE_030 AGE_030_new AGE_031`, `@F` will contain `"AGE_030", "AGE_030_new", "AGE_031"`. From this, the following mapping is created: `"AGE_030" => "AGE_030_old", "AGE_030_new" => "AGE_030"`. Finally, we apply the mapping and rebuild the line.

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)