# remove multiline text blocks

Tags: perl, sed

In this `alpha.txt` text file:

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.

:::info lecture
Duis eget
laoreet nunc.
:::

Etiam malesuada in
velit
in

   rhoncus:
   :::warning lecture
    Sed pretium justo eu
   tortor vehicula,

   tristique
   :::

   opcar kel

 Sed pretium

 justo.
```

**I'd like to "remove" all `:::* lecture` `*` `:::` multiline blocks.**

---

I'd like a POSIX `cmd` (using `sed` for example or `perl`) that a such call:

```
$ cat alpha.txt | cmd
```

exactly outputs:

```
Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit.


Etiam malesuada in
velit
in

   rhoncus:

   opcar kel

 Sed pretium

 justo.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 cat alpha.txt | perl -ne 'print unless /^\s*:::\S+ lecture\s*$/ ... /^\s*:::\s*$/'
```

---

Deparsed version of perl one liner:

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) { 
  print $_ unless /^\s*:::\S+ lecture\s*$/ ... /^\s*:::\s*$/;
}
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat` can be eliminated as follows: `perl -ne'...' <alpha.txt` and `perl -ne'...' alpha.txt` See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed '/:::.*lecture/,/:::/d' file
```