# Perl multi line regex match and remove

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text file that I am processing inside perl script.
How do I remove 2 or more lines that contains only `*`.
Input:

```
some text
*
some text
*
*
some text
*
*
*
```

I want to the text to look like this:

```
some text
*
some text
*
some text
*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the whole file in.

```
perl -0777pe's/^\*\n\K(\*\n)+//mg'
```

(The above won't work as written if the line terminator is missing from the last line.)

Working line by line is also rather simple since there's no need to look ahead.

```
perl -ne'print if !$flag || !/^\*$/; $flag = /^\*$/;'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can slurp, or anyway read your entire file into a string (today computer should have enough memory for that) and substitute any sequence of special lines with one only.

```
use English;
my $contents = do { local $/; <> };
chomp $contents;
$contents .= $RS;
$contents =~ s/^(\*$RS)+/\1/mg;
```

The 'm' modifier set the '^' anchor to recognise any line's begin, instead of the begin of the entire string.

Comment: `\1` is a regex pattern (that matches what the first capture matched). It makes no sense to use in string literals. You should be using `$1`, and Perl issues a warning saying as much. (You could also use the slightly faster `*\n`.)

Comment: `use English; ...$RS...` is a obfuscated way of writing `...\n...`

Comment: The use of \n works; I personally prefer $RS which is the input record separator in the current operating system eventually adapted to specific needs.
Definition of $<digits> from perlvar: ... Mnemonic: like \digits

Comment: `$RS` is `"\n"` on all OSs.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's rather weird that you use `$RS` in some places and `$/` in others. Same var!

Comment: To be specific: all magic of "record separator of the current operating system" is performed by the literal "\n" itself, or the `:crlf` layer if it should be translated from CRLF on that OS. `$RS` does not get you anything extra, except that it can be changed.

Answer (score -1):

Other possible solution with 'one liner' is

```
perl -0777 -pe "s/(\n\*)+/$1/g" regex_stars.txt
```

Input

```
some text
*
some text
*
*
some text
*
*
*
```

Output

```
some text
*
some text
*
some text
*
```

Comment: Fails for `"abc\n*\n*def\n"`  and for `"*\n*\nxyz\n"`

Comment: @ikegami - original post has different format than what your refer to.

Comment: No edits have been made to the OP (except possibly in the first 5 minutes after posting, but you answered 30 minutes later). Either way, this answer doesn't answer the question as it stands.

Comment: @ikegami - I once more in my answer added _Input_ block and _Output_ block and rerun the command. I do not see any difference from from OP's input/output.

Comment: Why are you spamming me with irrelevant comments?

Comment: The point is that it produces expected result with provided data by OP and you if first line is text followed by double `*` as in OP's example. OP's question _How do I remove 2 or more lines that contains only `*`_.

Comment: @ikegami -- in OP's post no word that `*` followed by anything else your point 1 is not applicable, point 2 also is not applicable as OP's sample does not contain `*` on first line -- although it might be the case. I gave an idea but not solution for all possible cases [two `*` on same line, two `*` on same line separated by other symbols and so on].

Comment: You are mistaken. The OP clearly said the lines must contain *only* `*`. Read the passage you just quoted. So you are removing lines and you shouldn't, and you aren't removing lines that you should

Comment: @ikegami -- where OP said that one of the line with `*` can be followed by any other symbol? Why did you bring this case into equation? Exactly lines must contain only `*` and nothing else (no spaces tabs or `def` as in your samples).

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, your solution doesn't handle that format. You should document your code's limitations. Because you didn't, I had to do it for you