# Perl oneliner to extract host and port from URL

Tags: perl, awk

I am aiming to extract host and port number from the url. Could you please update me any examples to do it using perl regex or sed/awk etc?

```
echo "https://xxxx:port/services"
```

I am looking for an oneliner to extract host and port.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MURI -nle'$u = URI->new($_); printf "%s:%s\n", $u->host, $u->port'
```

- Works even if the port is implied. (e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/`)
- Works for HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and some others that have the concept of a host and port.

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Comment: Fantastic, Thanks a lot for your quick reply .

Answer (score 2):

I do this so often that I made a little `sprintf`-like utility for it: [App::url](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/App::URL). This isn't useful if you can't install the module and easily use the command-line program, but locally it's quite helpful to extract and rearrange things:

```
$ url "%h:%p" http://www.example.com/a/b/c
www.example.com:80

$ url "%h:%p" http://www.example.com/a/b/c https://www2.example.org:444
www.example.com:80
www2.example.org:444

$ url "%h -> %I" http://www.example.com/a/b/c
www.example.com -> 93.184.216.34
```

Often I use this with a little AppleScript I wrote to [get all the URLs from all the tabs in Safari](https://gist.github.com/briandfoy/e601ba5b888fe153c2d853ed469452f2):

```
$ safari-tabs 2>&1 | xargs url %h
www.google.com
github.com
dnschecker.org
securitytrails.com
st.aticpan.org
```