# How to increment a text in a file by range with any windows or unix/linux commandline script?

Tags: perl

Is there any windows or unix/linux commandline script that can do this?I.e the word "boss" should be incremented from 1 to 60,then 1 to 60 again.

I have a file that contains a list of text like so;

```
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
.
.
.
```

I want the output to be:

```
She is the new boss1
She is the new boss2
She is the new boss3
.
.
.
She is the new boss60
She is the new boss1
She is the new boss2
She is the new boss3
.
.
.
She is the new boss60
.
.
.
```

So,far I use this

```
perl -i.bak -ape "s/"old-text"/$&.++$A /ge" input.txt && del input.txt.bak
```

to do repeated increment but the output it produces is not what I want.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe 's/\bboss\b\K/(++$n > 60 ? $n=1 : $n)/eg' file
```

Word boundaries `\b` have been added around `boss` to prevent matching `bossy` or `embossed`.

---

Originally, you used `$&.++$A`:

- The incremented variable needs to be reset conditionally. A [ternary `?:` expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator) can be used to achieve that.
- `$&` can be removed by using the [PCRE `\K` escape](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions).

It's easier to *not* use the save-in-place `-i` option until you know that the processing being applied is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
perl -ple'$_ .= ($. - 1) % 60 + 1'
```

`$.` is the current line number.

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Answer (score 0):

This Linux command may do:

```sh
i=1 && while read f; do echo "$f$i"; i=$(( i+1 )); done <original_file.txt > new_file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk:

```
$ echo "She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss
She is the new boss" | awk -v max=3 '{cnt>=max ? cnt=1:cnt++; $NF=$NF cnt;} 1'
```

Prints:

```
She is the new boss1
She is the new boss2
She is the new boss3
She is the new boss1
She is the new boss2
She is the new boss3
She is the new boss1
She is the new boss2
```

So just change the input `max` to 60 and that should work as your example describes.

---

For a file, just do:

```
$ awk -v max=60 '{cnt>=max ? cnt=1:cnt++; $NF=$NF cnt;} 1' your_file
```

Comment: how can I do this for the text in a file?@dawg

Answer (score 0):

I don't think python is clean in this task. But I write this for you.

```
import re


class LineReplacer(object):
    def __init__(self, replace_word, max_word_count):
        self.word_index = 1
        self.word_to_replace = replace_word
        self.max_word_count = max_word_count

    @property
    def word_regex(self):
        return re.compile(f"(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9]){self.word_to_replace}(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])")

    def replace_function(self, match):
        current_index = self.word_index
        if self.word_index < self.max_word_count:
            self.word_index += 1
        else:
            self.word_index = 1
        return f"{match.group()}{current_index}"

    def replace_file(self, input_file_path, output_file_path):
        output = open(output_file_path, "w")
        with open(input_file_path, "r") as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                new_line = self.word_regex.sub(self.replace_function, line)
                output.write(new_line)
        output.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    replacer = LineReplacer("boss", 60)
    replacer.replace_file("test.txt", "output.txt")
```

This will generate a new file.