# How do I grep/awk multiple lines from a cluster based on a pattern?

Tags: linux, perl, awk, grep

is there a way I can grep/awk multiple lines from a cluster based on a pattern?

I have a file as follows:

File.txt

```
>Cluster1
1 rabbit eats carrot 
2 Lion is the king of jungle
3 Dogs loves toys 
4 Cats loves mice 
>Cluster2
1 Horse loves grass 
2 Giraffes love leaves
3 Hippos love water
>Cluster3
1 Snakes love trees 
2 Sharks love fish
3 Tigers love bushes 
4 Cats love toys
5 Dogs love food
>Cluster4
1 Leopards love running 
2 Dogs love toys
3 Cats love food
>Cluster5
1 rabbit eats carrot 
2 Leopards love running
3 Cats love food
```

And the pattern is - "Dogs", I would like the output to be:

```
>Cluster1
1 rabbit eats carrot 
2 Lion is the king of jungle
3 Dogs loves toys 
4 Cats loves mice
>Cluster3
1 Snakes love trees 
2 Sharks love fish
3 Tigers love bushes 
4 Cats love toys
5 Dogs love food
>Cluster4
1 Leopards love running 
2 Dogs love toys
3 Cats love food
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
perl -0777ne'print grep /\bDogs\b/, split /^(?=>)/m, $_' file
```

or

```sh
perl -ne'
   sub p { print $buf if $buf =~ /\bDogs\b/; }
   if (/^>/) { p(); $buf = ""; }
   $buf .= $_;
   END { p() }
' file
```

Notes:

- The first version loads the entire file into memory (but not the second).
- Both versions search the first line of the record as well as the subsequent lines.
- You can place the second program all on one line if you want.
- These address two bugs in karakfa's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64436472/589924):

  - These don't add a leading blank line if the first record doesn't match.
  - These don't remove the final line feed if the last record doesn't match.
- Related: [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).

Comment: Thank you ikegami! Worked like a charm! And thank you for the explanation - its really useful.

Comment: I didn't really explain them. /// The first reads the whole file as a line (`-0777`), splits it on the zero-width string that precedes a `>` at the start of line, filters out the blocks that don't match the word `Dogs`, then print those that remain. /// The second accumulate lines until it sees `>` at the start of a line. Then, it prints the accumulated lines if they contain the word `Dogs`. Either way, the accumulated lines are cleared. The check is performed once more at the end of the file.

Comment: Wow - Thanks ikegami!

Answer (score 2):

with multi-char RS support (i.e. `gawk`)

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)>Cluster' -v ORS='' '/Dogs/{print rt $0} {rt=RT}' file

>Cluster1
1 rabbit eats carrot
2 Lion is the king of jungle
3 Dogs loves toys
4 Cats loves mice
>Cluster3
1 Snakes love trees
2 Sharks love fish
3 Tigers love bushes
4 Cats love toys
5 Dogs love food
>Cluster4
1 Leopards love running
2 Dogs love toys
3 Cats love food
```

Comment: @ikegami It won't capture the first one, where there is no preceding new line.

Comment: Yeah, the default value for RS is a line feed, so saying the first line must start with the value of RS makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami it won't be captured as a record separator but part of the first record instead. Easy to test, for example not printing `rt` will show.

Comment: @ikegami it's not just style, but idiomatic use.

Comment: There's a small bug: Your solution displays a leading blank line if the first record doesn't match. (`/\bDogs\b/` is probably better than `/Dogs/`.) (This is probably a FASTA file, in which case `>` is better than `>Cluster`.) Deleted my other comments.

Comment: Correct, it's either leading blank line or ending blank line with slight change with this approach. Pattern will match as a regex, for word match you can add the boundaries. Not clear in the question.

Comment: Thanks karakfa - I should have made it clear in the question that it is a FASTA file. But I really appreciate your answer using awk - which I could use for other things!

Answer (score 0):

Demo code which takes an argument of search parameter, reads file line by line (low memory requirements).

Replace `<DATA>` with filehandle for processing a real input file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = shift || 'Dogs';
my $found = 0;
my $block;

while( <DATA> ) {
    next if /^\s*\z/;      # skip blank lines
    if( />Cluster\d+/ ) {
        print $block if $found;
        $found = 0;
        $block = $_;
    } else {
        $found = 1 if /\b$regex\b/;
        $block .= $_;
    }
}

print $block if $found;

__DATA__
>Cluster1
1 rabbit eats carrot 
2 Lion is the king of jungle
3 Dogs loves toys 
4 Cats loves mice 
>Cluster2
1 Horse loves grass 
2 Giraffes love leaves
3 Hippos love water
>Cluster3
1 Snakes love trees 
2 Sharks love fish
3 Tigers love bushes
4 Cats love toys
5 Dogs love food
>Cluster4
1 Leopards love running 
2 Dogs love toys
3 Cats love food
>Cluster5
1 rabbit eats carrot 
2 Leopards love running
3 Cats love food
```

Output

```
>Cluster1
1 rabbit eats carrot
2 Lion is the king of jungle
3 Dogs loves toys
4 Cats loves mice
>Cluster3
1 Snakes love trees
2 Sharks love fish
3 Tigers love bushes
4 Cats love toys
5 Dogs love food
>Cluster4
1 Leopards love running
2 Dogs love toys
3 Cats love food
```

Comment: That never prints the last record, even if it matches. (Also, its calling convention means you can't replace `<DATA>` with `<>`, so it's not actually usable.)

Comment: @ikegami -- fixed print of last found record. Why do you talking about `<>` when I referred to `<$fh>`? You need to check your head?

Comment: I tried the code and it worked! But I have to give the point to ikegami for this one as its an easy one liner for  the command line. But thank you so much for answering!

Comment: And it did print the last record :)

Comment: @cms72 Re "*And it did print the last record :)*", Try again. It will never print the last record (`Cluster5`), even if you add `Dogs` to it.

Comment: Ah I see - I was thinking the last record being the last cluster with Dogs in it (i.e Cluster 4). But yes, youre right - if I add Dogs to Cluster 5, it won't print cluster 5. Sorry Polar Bear - but thank you anyway!