# reset state variables on next file in `perl -n` one-liner

Tags: perl

I'm processing multiple files with `find ... | xargs perl -ne` and when I proceed to next file I need to reset some variables like `gawk 'BEGINFILE {}'` does.

As a workaround, I check that the current filename changed. Is there a cleaner way?

```
if ($oldARGV ne $ARGV) { $oldARGV = $ARGV; $var1=""; ... } ...
```

Comment: @Dawg sorry I meant `gawk` `BEGINFILE`

Comment: Why are you using xargs? Perl is perfectly capable of processing multiple files, and it is much cleaner to handle arguments inside Perl than try to compare old arguments to xargs.

Comment: Re "*Perl is perfectly capable of processing multiple files*", @TLP, You just answered your own question :) On a non-GNU system, you'd want to `xargs` to take advantage of that ability. See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`eof`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof) with no argument (Or with `eof ARGV`):

```sh
$ perl -nE 'say "Done with file $ARGV" if eof' *.txt
Done with file a.txt
Done with file b.txt
```

Comment: @basin, I'm not sure what you mean. There are no lines in empty files, so the loop is never entered for an empty file, so how can code that is never executed "not work"?

Comment: @ikegami I think they meant to say that -- that this way they won't see the empty files.

Comment: @basin  the `@ARGV` contains names of all files given on the command line.  Then it'd just be about how to organize your code to track files, and combining `eof` and `@ARGV` may well come out quite clear and nice to look at.

Comment: @zdim, Re "*that this way they won't see the empty files*", Except the OP is already using `ARGV`, so they're already skipping empty files, and they didn't ask to change that. There's some conflicting information here, so clarification is needed.