# Replace two newlines with a single one and more than two with two newlines

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this:

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3



Line 4

Line 5



Line 6
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Line 4
Line 5

Line 6
```

I.e. replace two consecutive newlines with a single one and more than two with two newlines?

Comment: This might work for you GNU sed `sed '/\S/!{N;//D;:a;N;//!ba;s/.*\n\n/\n/}' file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the sequences of line feeds, this is what we want:

```
\n       -> \n    (No change)
\n\n     -> \n
\n\n\n+  -> \n\n
```

The simple solution involves loading the entire file into memory.

```sh
perl -0777pe's/\n\n?\K\n+//g'
```

If you want to avoid that, you can use the following:

```sh
perl -ne'
   chomp;
   $b = length ? 0 : $b+1;
   CORE::say if $b==0 || $b==2;
'
```

`$b` stands for "blank", and contains the number of blank lines encountered in a row.

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).

Answer (score 2):

In Perl: To match consecutive newlines using a regex, you cannot read in line-by-line mode. Which is why we slurp the file into a single string.

```
my $str = do { local $/; <DATA> };   # slurp the file into a single string
$str =~ s/\n\n?\K\n+//g;             
print $str;
```

The substitution regex matches a single newline `\n`, followed by an optional newline `\n?`, which it keeps `\K`, followed by 1 or more newlines `\n+`, which it removes. Since all quantifiers are greedy, this will allow the `?` to preserve the case of two newlines when there are 3 or more.

```
Case     \n\n?\K\n+    explanation                   result
\n        1 x    x     no match, no substitution     no change
\n\n      1 0    1     match, skip, match 1 time     \n remove \n
\n\n\n+   1 1    1+    match, match, match 1+ times  \n\n remove \n+
```

Or if you like it as a one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -pe's/\n\n?\K\n+//g' file
```

Add `-i` option to in-place edit a file when you are satisfied the changes work as expected. `-i.bak` to save backup.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out myself:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\n\n/\n/g' file
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks. It works for 0-3 blank lines, but not for 4+

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {minus2 = "a"; minus1 = "a";}{if($0==""){if(minus1=="" && minus2!=""){print $0}}else{print $0}; minus2 = minus1; minus1 = $0}' yourfile.txt
```

Explanation: to decide if to print current line I need to know content of two previous lines - I keep it as `minus2` and `minus1`. In `BEGIN` I set them (any value can be used, which `!=""`). Above might be presented in pseudo-code as follow *for every line do*:

```
if line is empty:
    if previous line is empty and previous previous non-empty:
        print line
    else:
        do nothing
else:
    print line
```

Then I update `minus1` and `minus2` so it would have correct values for next line.
Simply speaking I did print solely 2nd empty line from every group of empty lines.