# Perl command to change file EOL and saving the file with the same name

Tags: perl, terminal, debian

I am using this perl command on my debian to change my file EOL:

```
perl -p -e 's/\n/\r\n/' < ~/scripts/bite/EOL/*.csv > ~/scripts/bite/sent/samefilename.csv
```

Every day there will be a new file in the "EOL" directory with a different name and it always has only 1 file in the directory, so I am using "*" to take whatever file is in it.
But i need to save the new file with the same name as the file I chose to change without manually entering the file name to the command. Eventually this goes into my cronjob, so everything would be automatic.

EDIT: Fixed my problem by using "unix2dos"

Comment: `perl -pie` comes to mind, but then you'd have to copy the file to the target dir first and read it from there. Or copy it somewhere else, process it, then copy it to the target.

Comment: Why not to use command `unix2dos` or editor `vim` ( :set ff=dos)?

Comment: @PolarBear I am open to all suggestions as well yes. Il check them out.

Comment: @PolarBear I got my problem solved with "unix2dos", thank you. Could you make an answer so i could accept?

Comment: Per your request I've added the answer (someone might find it useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux has command `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` for converting eol from MS Windows/DOS to UNIX format. Perhaps it is easiest solution for described problem.

- [unix2dos](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unix2dos)
- [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `unix2dos` utility, but you can also use

```sh
perl -pe's/\n/\r\n/' -i file.csv
```

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).

Your program and this one only works on unix systems.