# what is the most elegant way to manipulate an arbitrary unicode character in perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, unix, unicode, hex

Consider a unicode character, such as zero-width space, which is not on any conventional keyboard and is not part of any human writing system. Suppose one wants to use perl to remove this character from a string, or one wants to print the character in bash unix.

This post reviews how one can do these things using hexadecimal code, and then asks: Is there a **more direct** (or elegant) way to do these things, using perhaps the decimal representation of the character?

The "zero-width space"  http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200B.html
shows up occasionally in text files.

For instance, on a macbook pro, from Messages.app, I saved an sms conversation as pdf. Then I opened the pdf in Preview, copied all, and pasted the clipboard into a file `z`. Then `less z` showed many instances of `<U+200B>`,
and when I opened it in `vim` it showed up as `<200b>`.

Similarly, "pop directional formatting", http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/202C.html, shows up when I copy and paste a phone number from the telephone field of Contacts.app.

Often I want to get the **plain text** from a string---anything that a human being would actually want to read, including letters in any language such as French é, Greek β, Arabic, Chinese and of course tab, space, and newline---without other characters.

This is because the other characters can cause problems. Not only are they a distraction in less and vim, but they seem to cause
[LaTeX](https://www.tug.org/begin.html),
pdflatex, to throw an error.

One can remove "zero-length space" as follows:

1. go to the url for the character, as cited above
2. scroll down to the table titled "Encodings (Unicode characters converter)"
3. on the UTF-8 row, find the text "E2 80 8B"
4. By hand, convert this to `\xe2\x80\x8b`
5. `perl -p -e 's/\xe2\x80\x8b//g;' myfile`

Using the same approach, one can print the character:

`printf '\xe2\x80\x8b'`

But on the same row
in http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200B.html
where one obtains the triad of hexadecimal numbers, one also finds that the decimal representation is `14844043`. Is there a way to use this decimal representation, or some other approach more direct than pasting together three hexadecimal codes?

Comment: You can play with the UTF-8 encoding (or any encoding really) if you have the raw data. But, Perl can handle all of those details for you if you treat it as character (decoded) data.

Answer (score 4):

Elegance is in the eye of the beholder.

But, the `-C` switch enables Perl's unicode handling, so you can take advantage of that.

```
perl -CD -wpe 's/\x{200B}//g' file
```

Also, you can use `\N` to specify the full names of the characters:

```
perl -CD -wpe 's/\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}//g' file
```

See [perlrun](http://p3rl.org/perlrun) for the explanation of the details of `-C`.
In particular, `-CD` is equivalent to `-Cio`, which means "make UTF-8 the default PerlIO layer for input and output streams".

Answer (score 4):

To remove U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE specifically:

```sh
perl -CSD -pe's/\x{200B}//g'
perl -CSD -pe's/\N{U+200B}//g'
perl -CSD -pe's/\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}//g'
```

`-CSD` handles encoding/decoding STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR/ARGV. (UTF-8, specifically.)

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).

---

That said, it sounds like you want a more general approach that would match "characters like ZERO WIDTH SPACE", not just ZERO WIDTH SPACE. But it's unclear what that means. Here are the properties ZERO WIDTH SPACE has:

```
$ uniprops -a1 200B
U+200B ‹U+200B› \N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}
\pC
\p{Cf}
All
Any
Assigned
C
Other
Case_Ignorable
CI
Cf
Format
Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded
CWKCF
Common
Zyyy
Default_Ignorable_Code_Point
DI
General_Punctuation
InPunctuation
Graph
X_POSIX_Graph
Print
X_POSIX_Print
Unicode
Age=1.1
Age=V1_1
Bidi_Class=BN
Bidi_Class=Boundary_Neutral
BC=BN
Bidi_Paired_Bracket_Type=None
Block=General_Punctuation
BLK=Punctuation
Block=Punctuation
Canonical_Combining_Class=0
Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered
CCC=NR
Canonical_Combining_Class=NR
Script_Extensions=Common
Decomposition_Type=None
DT=None
East_Asian_Width=Neutral
Grapheme_Cluster_Break=CN
Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Control
GCB=CN
Hangul_Syllable_Type=NA
Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable
HST=NA
Identifier_Status=Restricted
Identifier_Type=Default_Ignorable
Indic_Positional_Category=NA
InPC=NA
Indic_Syllabic_Category=Other
InSC=Other
Joining_Group=No_Joining_Group
JG=NoJoiningGroup
Joining_Type=T
Joining_Type=Transparent
JT=T
Line_Break=ZW
Line_Break=ZWSpace
LB=ZW
Numeric_Type=None
NT=None
Numeric_Value=NaN
NV=NaN
Present_In=1.1
IN=1.1
Present_In=2.0
IN=2.0
Present_In=V2_0
Present_In=2.1
IN=2.1
Present_In=V2_1
Present_In=3.0
IN=3.0
Present_In=V3_0
Present_In=3.1
IN=3.1
Present_In=V3_1
Present_In=3.2
IN=3.2
Present_In=V3_2
Present_In=4.0
IN=4.0
Present_In=V4_0
Present_In=4.1
IN=4.1
Present_In=V4_1
Present_In=5.0
IN=5.0
Present_In=V5_0
Present_In=5.1
IN=5.1
Present_In=V5_1
Present_In=5.2
IN=5.2
Present_In=V5_2
Present_In=6.0
IN=6.0
Present_In=V6_0
Present_In=6.1
IN=6.1
Present_In=V6_1
Present_In=6.2
IN=6.2
Present_In=V6_2
Present_In=6.3
IN=6.3
Present_In=V6_3
Present_In=7.0
IN=7.0
Present_In=V7_0
Present_In=8.0
IN=8.0
Present_In=V8_0
Present_In=9.0
IN=9.0
Present_In=V9_0
Present_In=10.0
IN=10.0
Present_In=V10_0
Present_In=11.0
IN=11.0
Present_In=V11_0
Present_In=12.0
IN=12.0
Present_In=V12_0
Present_In=12.1
IN=12.1
Present_In=V12_1
Present_In=13.0
IN=13.0
Present_In=V13_0
Script=Common
SC=Zyyy
Script=Zyyy
Scx=Zyyy
Script_Extensions=Zyyy
Sentence_Break=FO
Sentence_Break=Format
SB=FO
Vertical_Orientation=R
Vertical_Orientation=Rotated
Vo=R
Word_Break=Other
WB=XX
Word_Break=XX
```

The first two might be the ones of interest two.

---

**`\p{General_Category=Format}` aka `\p{Gc=Cf}` aka `\p{Format}` aka `\p{Cf}`**

```sh
perl -CSD -pe's/\p{Cf}//g'
```

This property is shared by the following 161 Code Points:

```
$ unichars -a '\p{Cf}' | cat
 ---- U+000AD SOFT HYPHEN
 ---- U+00600 ARABIC NUMBER SIGN
 ---- U+00601 ARABIC SIGN SANAH
 ---- U+00602 ARABIC FOOTNOTE MARKER
 ---- U+00603 ARABIC SIGN SAFHA
 ---- U+00604 ARABIC SIGN SAMVAT
 ---- U+00605 ARABIC NUMBER MARK ABOVE
 ---- U+0061C ARABIC LETTER MARK
 ---- U+006DD ARABIC END OF AYAH
 ---- U+0070F SYRIAC ABBREVIATION MARK
 ---- U+008E2 ARABIC DISPUTED END OF AYAH
 ---- U+0180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
 ---- U+0200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE
 ---- U+0200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
 ---- U+0200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER
 ---- U+0200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
 ---- U+0200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
 ---- U+0202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
 ---- U+0202B RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING
 ---- U+0202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
 ---- U+0202D LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
 ---- U+0202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE
 ---- U+02060 WORD JOINER
 ---- U+02061 FUNCTION APPLICATION
 ---- U+02062 INVISIBLE TIMES
 ---- U+02063 INVISIBLE SEPARATOR
 ---- U+02064 INVISIBLE PLUS
 ---- U+02066 LEFT-TO-RIGHT ISOLATE
 ---- U+02067 RIGHT-TO-LEFT ISOLATE
 ---- U+02068 FIRST STRONG ISOLATE
 ---- U+02069 POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE
 ---- U+0206A INHIBIT SYMMETRIC SWAPPING
 ---- U+0206B ACTIVATE SYMMETRIC SWAPPING
 ---- U+0206C INHIBIT ARABIC FORM SHAPING
 ---- U+0206D ACTIVATE ARABIC FORM SHAPING
 ---- U+0206E NATIONAL DIGIT SHAPES
 ---- U+0206F NOMINAL DIGIT SHAPES
 ---- U+0FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+0FFF9 INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION ANCHOR
 ---- U+0FFFA INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION SEPARATOR
 ---- U+0FFFB INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION TERMINATOR
 ---- U+110BD KAITHI NUMBER SIGN
 ---- U+110CD KAITHI NUMBER SIGN ABOVE
 ---- U+13430 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH VERTICAL JOINER
 ---- U+13431 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH HORIZONTAL JOINER
 ---- U+13432 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT TOP START
 ---- U+13433 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT BOTTOM START
 ---- U+13434 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT TOP END
 ---- U+13435 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT BOTTOM END
 ---- U+13436 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH OVERLAY MIDDLE
 ---- U+13437 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH BEGIN SEGMENT
 ---- U+13438 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH END SEGMENT
 ---- U+1BCA0 SHORTHAND FORMAT LETTER OVERLAP
 ---- U+1BCA1 SHORTHAND FORMAT CONTINUING OVERLAP
 ---- U+1BCA2 SHORTHAND FORMAT DOWN STEP
 ---- U+1BCA3 SHORTHAND FORMAT UP STEP
 ---- U+1D173 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN BEAM
 ---- U+1D174 MUSICAL SYMBOL END BEAM
 ---- U+1D175 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN TIE
 ---- U+1D176 MUSICAL SYMBOL END TIE
 ---- U+1D177 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN SLUR
 ---- U+1D178 MUSICAL SYMBOL END SLUR
 ---- U+1D179 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN PHRASE
 ---- U+1D17A MUSICAL SYMBOL END PHRASE
 ---- U+E0001 LANGUAGE TAG
 ---- U+E0020 TAG SPACE
 ---- U+E0021 TAG EXCLAMATION MARK
 ---- U+E0022 TAG QUOTATION MARK
 ---- U+E0023 TAG NUMBER SIGN
 ---- U+E0024 TAG DOLLAR SIGN
 ---- U+E0025 TAG PERCENT SIGN
 ---- U+E0026 TAG AMPERSAND
 ---- U+E0027 TAG APOSTROPHE
 ---- U+E0028 TAG LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ---- U+E0029 TAG RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ---- U+E002A TAG ASTERISK
 ---- U+E002B TAG PLUS SIGN
 ---- U+E002C TAG COMMA
 ---- U+E002D TAG HYPHEN-MINUS
 ---- U+E002E TAG FULL STOP
 ---- U+E002F TAG SOLIDUS
 ---- U+E0030 TAG DIGIT ZERO
 ---- U+E0031 TAG DIGIT ONE
 ---- U+E0032 TAG DIGIT TWO
 ---- U+E0033 TAG DIGIT THREE
 ---- U+E0034 TAG DIGIT FOUR
 ---- U+E0035 TAG DIGIT FIVE
 ---- U+E0036 TAG DIGIT SIX
 ---- U+E0037 TAG DIGIT SEVEN
 ---- U+E0038 TAG DIGIT EIGHT
 ---- U+E0039 TAG DIGIT NINE
 ---- U+E003A TAG COLON
 ---- U+E003B TAG SEMICOLON
 ---- U+E003C TAG LESS-THAN SIGN
 ---- U+E003D TAG EQUALS SIGN
 ---- U+E003E TAG GREATER-THAN SIGN
 ---- U+E003F TAG QUESTION MARK
 ---- U+E0040 TAG COMMERCIAL AT
 ---- U+E0041 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
 ---- U+E0042 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
 ---- U+E0043 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
 ---- U+E0044 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
 ---- U+E0045 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
 ---- U+E0046 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
 ---- U+E0047 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
 ---- U+E0048 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
 ---- U+E0049 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
 ---- U+E004A TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
 ---- U+E004B TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
 ---- U+E004C TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
 ---- U+E004D TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
 ---- U+E004E TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
 ---- U+E004F TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
 ---- U+E0050 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
 ---- U+E0051 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
 ---- U+E0052 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
 ---- U+E0053 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
 ---- U+E0054 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
 ---- U+E0055 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
 ---- U+E0056 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
 ---- U+E0057 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
 ---- U+E0058 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
 ---- U+E0059 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
 ---- U+E005A TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
 ---- U+E005B TAG LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
 ---- U+E005C TAG REVERSE SOLIDUS
 ---- U+E005D TAG RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
 ---- U+E005E TAG CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
 ---- U+E005F TAG LOW LINE
 ---- U+E0060 TAG GRAVE ACCENT
 ---- U+E0061 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER A
 ---- U+E0062 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER B
 ---- U+E0063 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER C
 ---- U+E0064 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER D
 ---- U+E0065 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER E
 ---- U+E0066 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER F
 ---- U+E0067 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER G
 ---- U+E0068 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER H
 ---- U+E0069 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER I
 ---- U+E006A TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER J
 ---- U+E006B TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER K
 ---- U+E006C TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER L
 ---- U+E006D TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER M
 ---- U+E006E TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER N
 ---- U+E006F TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER O
 ---- U+E0070 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER P
 ---- U+E0071 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
 ---- U+E0072 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER R
 ---- U+E0073 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER S
 ---- U+E0074 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER T
 ---- U+E0075 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER U
 ---- U+E0076 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER V
 ---- U+E0077 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER W
 ---- U+E0078 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER X
 ---- U+E0079 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
 ---- U+E007A TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
 ---- U+E007B TAG LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 ---- U+E007C TAG VERTICAL LINE
 ---- U+E007D TAG RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ---- U+E007E TAG TILDE
 ---- U+E007F CANCEL TAG
```

---

**`\p{General_Category=Other}` aka `\p{Gc=C}` aka `\p{Other}` aka `\p{C}` aka `\pC`**

```sh
perl -CSD -pe's/\pC//g'
```

`\p{General_Category=Other}` (`\pC`) includes:

- `\p{General_Category=Control}` (`\p{Cc}`): 65 Code Points
- `\p{General_Category=Format}` (`\p{Cf}`): 161 Code Points [Mentioned above]
- `\p{General_Category=Private_Use}` (`\p{Co}`): 137,468 Code Points
- `\p{General_Category=Unassigned}` (`\p{Cn}`): 830,672 Code Points
- `\p{General_Category=Surrogate}` (`\p{Cs}`): 2,048 Code Points

Of those 970,414, the following are the 226 named ones (equivalent to `[\p{Cc}\p{Cf}]`):

```
$ unichars -a '\pC' | cat
 ---- U+00000 NULL
 ---- U+00001 START OF HEADING
 ---- U+00002 START OF TEXT
 ---- U+00003 END OF TEXT
 ---- U+00004 END OF TRANSMISSION
 ---- U+00005 ENQUIRY
 ---- U+00006 ACKNOWLEDGE
 ---- U+00007 ALERT
 ---- U+00008 BACKSPACE
 ---- U+00009 CHARACTER TABULATION
 ---- U+0000A LINE FEED
 ---- U+0000B LINE TABULATION
 ---- U+0000C FORM FEED
 ---- U+0000D CARRIAGE RETURN
 ---- U+0000E SHIFT OUT
 ---- U+0000F SHIFT IN
 ---- U+00010 DATA LINK ESCAPE
 ---- U+00011 DEVICE CONTROL ONE
 ---- U+00012 DEVICE CONTROL TWO
 ---- U+00013 DEVICE CONTROL THREE
 ---- U+00014 DEVICE CONTROL FOUR
 ---- U+00015 NEGATIVE ACKNOWLEDGE
 ---- U+00016 SYNCHRONOUS IDLE
 ---- U+00017 END OF TRANSMISSION BLOCK
 ---- U+00018 CANCEL
 ---- U+00019 END OF MEDIUM
 ---- U+0001A SUBSTITUTE
 ---- U+0001B ESCAPE
 ---- U+0001C INFORMATION SEPARATOR FOUR
 ---- U+0001D INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE
 ---- U+0001E INFORMATION SEPARATOR TWO
 ---- U+0001F INFORMATION SEPARATOR ONE
 ---- U+0007F DELETE
 ---- U+00080 PADDING CHARACTER
 ---- U+00081 HIGH OCTET PRESET
 ---- U+00082 BREAK PERMITTED HERE
 ---- U+00083 NO BREAK HERE
 ---- U+00084 INDEX
 ---- U+00085 NEXT LINE
 ---- U+00086 START OF SELECTED AREA
 ---- U+00087 END OF SELECTED AREA
 ---- U+00088 CHARACTER TABULATION SET
 ---- U+00089 CHARACTER TABULATION WITH JUSTIFICATION
 ---- U+0008A LINE TABULATION SET
 ---- U+0008B PARTIAL LINE FORWARD
 ---- U+0008C PARTIAL LINE BACKWARD
 ---- U+0008D REVERSE LINE FEED
 ---- U+0008E SINGLE SHIFT TWO
 ---- U+0008F SINGLE SHIFT THREE
 ---- U+00090 DEVICE CONTROL STRING
 ---- U+00091 PRIVATE USE ONE
 ---- U+00092 PRIVATE USE TWO
 ---- U+00093 SET TRANSMIT STATE
 ---- U+00094 CANCEL CHARACTER
 ---- U+00095 MESSAGE WAITING
 ---- U+00096 START OF GUARDED AREA
 ---- U+00097 END OF GUARDED AREA
 ---- U+00098 START OF STRING
 ---- U+00099 SINGLE GRAPHIC CHARACTER INTRODUCER
 ---- U+0009A SINGLE CHARACTER INTRODUCER
 ---- U+0009B CONTROL SEQUENCE INTRODUCER
 ---- U+0009C STRING TERMINATOR
 ---- U+0009D OPERATING SYSTEM COMMAND
 ---- U+0009E PRIVACY MESSAGE
 ---- U+0009F APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND
 ---- U+000AD SOFT HYPHEN
 ---- U+00600 ARABIC NUMBER SIGN
 ---- U+00601 ARABIC SIGN SANAH
 ---- U+00602 ARABIC FOOTNOTE MARKER
 ---- U+00603 ARABIC SIGN SAFHA
 ---- U+00604 ARABIC SIGN SAMVAT
 ---- U+00605 ARABIC NUMBER MARK ABOVE
 ---- U+0061C ARABIC LETTER MARK
 ---- U+006DD ARABIC END OF AYAH
 ---- U+0070F SYRIAC ABBREVIATION MARK
 ---- U+008E2 ARABIC DISPUTED END OF AYAH
 ---- U+0180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
 ---- U+0200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE
 ---- U+0200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER
 ---- U+0200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER
 ---- U+0200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK
 ---- U+0200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK
 ---- U+0202A LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING
 ---- U+0202B RIGHT-TO-LEFT EMBEDDING
 ---- U+0202C POP DIRECTIONAL FORMATTING
 ---- U+0202D LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE
 ---- U+0202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE
 ---- U+02060 WORD JOINER
 ---- U+02061 FUNCTION APPLICATION
 ---- U+02062 INVISIBLE TIMES
 ---- U+02063 INVISIBLE SEPARATOR
 ---- U+02064 INVISIBLE PLUS
 ---- U+02066 LEFT-TO-RIGHT ISOLATE
 ---- U+02067 RIGHT-TO-LEFT ISOLATE
 ---- U+02068 FIRST STRONG ISOLATE
 ---- U+02069 POP DIRECTIONAL ISOLATE
 ---- U+0206A INHIBIT SYMMETRIC SWAPPING
 ---- U+0206B ACTIVATE SYMMETRIC SWAPPING
 ---- U+0206C INHIBIT ARABIC FORM SHAPING
 ---- U+0206D ACTIVATE ARABIC FORM SHAPING
 ---- U+0206E NATIONAL DIGIT SHAPES
 ---- U+0206F NOMINAL DIGIT SHAPES
 ---- U+0FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+0FFF9 INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION ANCHOR
 ---- U+0FFFA INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION SEPARATOR
 ---- U+0FFFB INTERLINEAR ANNOTATION TERMINATOR
 ---- U+110BD KAITHI NUMBER SIGN
 ---- U+110CD KAITHI NUMBER SIGN ABOVE
 ---- U+13430 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH VERTICAL JOINER
 ---- U+13431 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH HORIZONTAL JOINER
 ---- U+13432 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT TOP START
 ---- U+13433 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT BOTTOM START
 ---- U+13434 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT TOP END
 ---- U+13435 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH INSERT AT BOTTOM END
 ---- U+13436 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH OVERLAY MIDDLE
 ---- U+13437 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH BEGIN SEGMENT
 ---- U+13438 EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH END SEGMENT
 ---- U+1BCA0 SHORTHAND FORMAT LETTER OVERLAP
 ---- U+1BCA1 SHORTHAND FORMAT CONTINUING OVERLAP
 ---- U+1BCA2 SHORTHAND FORMAT DOWN STEP
 ---- U+1BCA3 SHORTHAND FORMAT UP STEP
 ---- U+1D173 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN BEAM
 ---- U+1D174 MUSICAL SYMBOL END BEAM
 ---- U+1D175 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN TIE
 ---- U+1D176 MUSICAL SYMBOL END TIE
 ---- U+1D177 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN SLUR
 ---- U+1D178 MUSICAL SYMBOL END SLUR
 ---- U+1D179 MUSICAL SYMBOL BEGIN PHRASE
 ---- U+1D17A MUSICAL SYMBOL END PHRASE
 ---- U+E0001 LANGUAGE TAG
 ---- U+E0020 TAG SPACE
 ---- U+E0021 TAG EXCLAMATION MARK
 ---- U+E0022 TAG QUOTATION MARK
 ---- U+E0023 TAG NUMBER SIGN
 ---- U+E0024 TAG DOLLAR SIGN
 ---- U+E0025 TAG PERCENT SIGN
 ---- U+E0026 TAG AMPERSAND
 ---- U+E0027 TAG APOSTROPHE
 ---- U+E0028 TAG LEFT PARENTHESIS
 ---- U+E0029 TAG RIGHT PARENTHESIS
 ---- U+E002A TAG ASTERISK
 ---- U+E002B TAG PLUS SIGN
 ---- U+E002C TAG COMMA
 ---- U+E002D TAG HYPHEN-MINUS
 ---- U+E002E TAG FULL STOP
 ---- U+E002F TAG SOLIDUS
 ---- U+E0030 TAG DIGIT ZERO
 ---- U+E0031 TAG DIGIT ONE
 ---- U+E0032 TAG DIGIT TWO
 ---- U+E0033 TAG DIGIT THREE
 ---- U+E0034 TAG DIGIT FOUR
 ---- U+E0035 TAG DIGIT FIVE
 ---- U+E0036 TAG DIGIT SIX
 ---- U+E0037 TAG DIGIT SEVEN
 ---- U+E0038 TAG DIGIT EIGHT
 ---- U+E0039 TAG DIGIT NINE
 ---- U+E003A TAG COLON
 ---- U+E003B TAG SEMICOLON
 ---- U+E003C TAG LESS-THAN SIGN
 ---- U+E003D TAG EQUALS SIGN
 ---- U+E003E TAG GREATER-THAN SIGN
 ---- U+E003F TAG QUESTION MARK
 ---- U+E0040 TAG COMMERCIAL AT
 ---- U+E0041 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
 ---- U+E0042 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER B
 ---- U+E0043 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
 ---- U+E0044 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER D
 ---- U+E0045 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
 ---- U+E0046 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
 ---- U+E0047 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G
 ---- U+E0048 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H
 ---- U+E0049 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
 ---- U+E004A TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J
 ---- U+E004B TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
 ---- U+E004C TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
 ---- U+E004D TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER M
 ---- U+E004E TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
 ---- U+E004F TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
 ---- U+E0050 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
 ---- U+E0051 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Q
 ---- U+E0052 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
 ---- U+E0053 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
 ---- U+E0054 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
 ---- U+E0055 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U
 ---- U+E0056 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER V
 ---- U+E0057 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER W
 ---- U+E0058 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
 ---- U+E0059 TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y
 ---- U+E005A TAG LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z
 ---- U+E005B TAG LEFT SQUARE BRACKET
 ---- U+E005C TAG REVERSE SOLIDUS
 ---- U+E005D TAG RIGHT SQUARE BRACKET
 ---- U+E005E TAG CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
 ---- U+E005F TAG LOW LINE
 ---- U+E0060 TAG GRAVE ACCENT
 ---- U+E0061 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER A
 ---- U+E0062 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER B
 ---- U+E0063 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER C
 ---- U+E0064 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER D
 ---- U+E0065 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER E
 ---- U+E0066 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER F
 ---- U+E0067 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER G
 ---- U+E0068 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER H
 ---- U+E0069 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER I
 ---- U+E006A TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER J
 ---- U+E006B TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER K
 ---- U+E006C TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER L
 ---- U+E006D TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER M
 ---- U+E006E TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER N
 ---- U+E006F TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER O
 ---- U+E0070 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER P
 ---- U+E0071 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER Q
 ---- U+E0072 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER R
 ---- U+E0073 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER S
 ---- U+E0074 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER T
 ---- U+E0075 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER U
 ---- U+E0076 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER V
 ---- U+E0077 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER W
 ---- U+E0078 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER X
 ---- U+E0079 TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER Y
 ---- U+E007A TAG LATIN SMALL LETTER Z
 ---- U+E007B TAG LEFT CURLY BRACKET
 ---- U+E007C TAG VERTICAL LINE
 ---- U+E007D TAG RIGHT CURLY BRACKET
 ---- U+E007E TAG TILDE
 ---- U+E007F CANCEL TAG
```

Comment: What is the equivalent of `-C` or `-S` or `-D` or `-CSD` inside a perl script? So that one calls the script rather than saying `perl -CSD` on the command line?

Comment: `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8);` (Actually does more, setting the default for `open` use in scope)