# search for a key value pair and append the value to other keys in unix

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I need to search for a key and append the value to every key:value pair in a Unix file

Input file data:

```
1A:trans_ref_id|10:account_no|20:cust_name|30:trans_amt|40:addr
1A:trans_ref_id|10A:ccard_no|20:cust_name|30:trans_amt|40:addr
```

My desired Output:

```
account_no|1A:trans_ref_id
account_no|10:account_no
account_no|20:cust_name
account_no|30:trans_amt
account_no|40:addr
ccard_no|1A:trans_ref_id
ccard_no|10A:ccard_no
ccard_no|20:cust_name
ccard_no|30:trans_amt
ccard_no|40:addr
```

Basically, I need the value of `10` or `10A` appended to every key:value pair and split into new lines. To be clear, this won't always be the second field.

I am new to sed, awk and perl. I started with extracting the value using awk:

```sh
awk -v FS="|" -v key="59" '$2 == key {print $2}' target.txt
```

Comment: `awk` with a field-separator of `'|'` and then `split()` on `':'` would go a long way to getting you started, [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents) You will find `split()` under [9.1.3 String-Manipulation Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions)

Comment: well, I am pretty new to string functions. But was trying with various perl and AWK options.

Comment: @nag, sure, please do add your attempted code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO. There is nothing wrong or right about your efforts, we all are here to learn from each other.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, thank you, I started with extracting the value using awk: awk -v FS="|" -v key="59" '$2 == key {print $2}' target.txt but my key can be present in any location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:***  To find `10` OR `10A` values in anywhere in line and then print as per that try following then.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
match($0,/(10|10A):[^|]*/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,":")
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    print arr[2],$i
  }
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                       ##Starting BEGIN section of this program.
  FS=OFS="|"                 ##Setting FS and OFS to | here.
}
match($0,/(10|10A):[^|]*/){  ##using match function to match either 10: till | OR 10A: till | here.
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,":") ##Splitting matched sub string into array arr with delmiter of : here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){        ##Running for loop for each field for each line.
    print arr[2],$i          ##Printing 2nd element of ar, along with current field.
  }
}'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="|"
}
{
  split($2,arr,":")
  print arr[2],$1
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    print arr[2],$i
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Hmm... What happened to, e.g. `account_no|10:account_no` and `ccard_no|10A:ccard_no` in the desired output `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks David sir, I have missed it, if I change it now so it becomes same as yours, so printing 1st column first and then using loop :)

Comment: You have nicely indented format -- I don't mind -- change away. Great minds think alike after all...

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However, the position of the key:value pair for 10 or 10A can vary in the record. Not always at $2.

Comment: @nag, Sure, please do check my EDIT answer once and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

```sh
# Looks for 10 or 10A
perl -F'\|' -lane'my ($id) = map /^10A?:(.*)/s, @F; print "$id|$_" for @F'
```

```sh
# Looks for 10 or 10<non-digit><maybe more>
perl -F'\|' -lane'my ($id) = map /^10(?:\D[^:]*)?:(.*)/s, @F; print "$id|$_" for @F'
```

- `-n` executes the program for each line of input.
- `-l` removes LF on read and adds it on print.
- `-a` splits the line on `|` (specified by `-F`) into `@F`.
- The first statement extracts what follows `:` in the field with id 10 or 10-plus-something.
- The second statement prints a line for each field.

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Comment: @Sundeep, Thanks, was just about to test. Apparently, `-F` takes a regex pattern, so it needs to be escaped for both the shell and the regex engine. The issue with the new version has also been fixed.

Comment: @nag, Re "*the position of the key:value pair for 10 or 10A can vary in the record. Not always at $2.*", I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Sundeep, It didn't work according to the additional info provided by the OP.

Comment: @Sundeep, The OP wasn't didn't specify whether `10B`, etc  should be accepted or not. I assumed the answer is either yes or `10B` will never happen.

Comment: @Sundeep Re "*or just `/10A?:([^|]+)/` instead of map*", No, that could match `10A:` inside of a value, or a key of `110A`, etc

Comment: @Sundeep, Still would fail by matching `110A`

Comment: Yeah realized that.. changed it to `/(?<![^|])10A?:([^|]+)/`

Comment: @Sundeep, Yeah, you could use that. Or `/(?:^|\|)10A?:([^|]*)/`. But at this point, I believe `map` becomes clearer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are still stuck on where to get started, you will use a *field-separator* and *output-field-separator* (`FS` and `OFS`) set equal to `'|'` that will split each record into fields at each `'|'`. Your fields are available as `$1, $2, ... $NF`. You care about getting, e.g. `account_no` from field two (`$2`) so you `split()` field two with the separator `':'` saving the split fields in an array (`a` used below). You want the second part from field two which will be in the 2nd array element `a[2]` to use as the new field-1 in output.

The rest is just looping over each field and outputting `a[2]` a separator and then the current field. You can do that with:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {split ($2,a,":"); for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print a[2],$i}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in `file`, the result would be:

```
account_no|1A:trans_ref_id
account_no|10:account_no
account_no|20:cust_name
account_no|30:trans_amt
account_no|40:addr
ccard_no|1A:trans_ref_id
ccard_no|10A:ccard_no
ccard_no|20:cust_name
ccard_no|30:trans_amt
ccard_no|40:addr
```

Which appears to be what you are after. Let me know if you have further questions.

**"10" or "10A" at Unknown Field**

You can handle the fields containing `"10"` and `"10A"` in any order. You just add a loop to loop over the fields and determine which holds `"10"` or `"10A"` and save the 2nd element from the array resulting from `split()` from that field. The rest is the same, e.g.

```
awk  '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" } 
    {   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
            split ($i,a,":")
            if (a[1]=="10"||a[1]=="10A"){ 
                key=a[2]
                break
            }
        }
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            print key, $i
    }
' file1
```

**Example Input**

```
1A:trans_ref_id|10:account_no|20:cust_name|30:trans_amt|40:addr
1A:trans_ref_id|20:cust_name|30:trans_amt|10A:ccard_no|40:addr
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
awk  '
>     BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
>     {   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
>             split ($i,a,":")
>             if (a[1]=="10"||a[1]=="10A"){
>                 key=a[2]
>                 break
>             }
>         }
>         for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
>             print key, $i
>     }
> ' file1
account_no|1A:trans_ref_id
account_no|10:account_no
account_no|20:cust_name
account_no|30:trans_amt
account_no|40:addr
ccard_no|1A:trans_ref_id
ccard_no|20:cust_name
ccard_no|30:trans_amt
ccard_no|10A:ccard_no
ccard_no|40:addr
```

Which picks up the proper new field 1 for output from the 4th field containing `"10A"` for the second line above.

Let em know if this is what you needed.

Comment: thank you for the solution. However, the position of the key:value pair for 10 or 10A can vary in the record. Not always at $2.

Comment: Very well explained answer

Comment: @nag the position for `10` or `10A` in the answer can very. They will simply appear in the output in the order of the fields where it appears in the input -- did you need something else? (in other words, I didn't do anything special to put them in that position). You can provide another variable (as your `key="match"` and locate the fields that contains the key and use that as your new field one -- completely up to you. That takes a tiny addition or two.

Comment: My input file data can sometimes be as : 1A:trans_ref_id|10:account_no|20:cust_name|30:trans_amt|40:addr
1A:trans_ref_id|20:cust_name|30:trans_amt|10A:ccard_no|40:addr

Comment: In that case are you saying you want `cust_name|10A:ccard_no`  before `cust_name|30:trans_amt` in the output?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, the output should always be the same as ccard_no|20:cust_name.

Comment: @nag -- thank you for making that clear. I have added another answer based on that requirement at the bottom of my original answer -- which should be what you needed.

Answer (score 3):

> I need the value of `10` or `10A` appended to every `key:value` pair

Going by these requirements, you may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}
match($0, /\|10A?:[^|]+/) {
   s = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
   sub(/.*:/, "", s)
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      print s, $i
}' file

account_no|1A:trans_ref_id
account_no|10:account_no
account_no|20:cust_name
account_no|30:trans_amt
account_no|40:addr
ccard_no|1A:trans_ref_id
ccard_no|10A:ccard_no
ccard_no|20:cust_name
ccard_no|30:trans_amt
ccard_no|40:addr
```

Comment: That's a crafty use of `match()` and `sub()` to accomplish the same goal!

Answer (score 1):

Perl script implementation

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $fname = shift || die "run as 'script.pl input_file key0 key1 ... key#'";

open my $fh, '<', $fname || die $!;

while( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    my %data = split(/[:\|]/, $_);
    for my $key (@ARGV) {
        if( $data{$key} ) {
            say "$data{$key}|$_" for split(/\|/,$_);
        }
    }
}

close $fh;
```

Run as `script.pl input_file 10 10A`

Output

```
account_no|1A:trans_ref_id
account_no|10:account_no
account_no|20:cust_name
account_no|30:trans_amt
account_no|40:addr
ccard_no|1A:trans_ref_id
ccard_no|10A:ccard_no
ccard_no|20:cust_name
ccard_no|30:trans_amt
ccard_no|40:addr
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate `perl` solution:

```sh
perl -pe '($id) = /(?<![^|])10A?:([^|]+)/; s/([^|]+)[|\n]/$id|$1\n/g'
```

- `($id) = /(?<![^|])10A?:([^|]+)/` this will capture the string after `10:` or `10A:` and save in `$id` variable. First such match in the line will be captured.
- `s/([^|]+)[|\n]/$id|$1\n/g` every field is then prefixed with value in `$id` and `|` character