# How to replace line in a file after htting a particular line in bash

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

So I have a simple use case, I have a file like

```
line_1
anything
anything
anything
aaa
line_2
line_3
anything
anything
anything
aaa
anything
anything
line_4
aaa
```

Now I have to replace the first `aaa` which comes after `line_3`.

Output-

```
line_1
anything
anything
anything
aaa
line_2
line_3
anything
anything
anything
YES REPLACE THIS
anything
anything
line_4
aaa
```

I was able to replace anything on the very next line using-

```bash
sed -i '/line_3/{n; s/aaa/YES REPLACE THIS/}' file.txt
```

But `aaa` is not of the next line, I do not know after how many lines it occurs, any solution using `sed`, `awk` or anything bash related will work, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a flag once it sees `line_3`, unset it once it finds and replaces the pattern

```
perl -wpe'if ($on) { $on = 0 if s/aaa/XXX/ }; $on = 1 if /^line_3$/' file
```

This only prints the resulting lines to screen.  If you want ot change the file ("in-place") add `-i` switch (`perl -i -wpe'...'`), or better `-i.bak` to keep a backup, too.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/line_3/{f=1} f&&/aaa/{$0="YES REPLACE THIS";f=0} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/line_3/,/line_4/{0,/^aaa/s/^aaa/YES REPLACE THIS/}' input_file
line_1
anything
anything
anything
aaa
line_2
line_3
anything
anything
anything
YES REPLACE THIS
anything
anything
line_4
aaa
```

Comment: *first `aaa`  after `line_3`* I would write: `/line_3/,/aaa/{ ...`  instead!

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I simply did not think of that. Don't know why. Thanks

Comment: Something simplier: `/line_3/,/^aaa$/{/^aaa$/s/^.*$/YES REPLACE THIS/}`

Comment: And for fun: `sed '/line_3/,/^aaa$/{//{/line_3/!s/^.*$/YES REPLACE THIS/}}'` will do the job too!

Answer (score 2):

Using just replacement in `perl`, let `file.txt` content be

```
line_1
anything
anything
anything
aaa
line_2
line_3
anything
anything
anything
aaa
anything
anything
line_4
aaa
```

then

```
perl -p -0777 -e 's/(line_3.*?)aaa\n/$1YES REPLACE THIS\n/s' file.txt
```

gives output

```
line_1
anything
anything
anything
aaa
line_2
line_3
anything
anything
anything
YES REPLACE THIS
anything
anything
line_4
aaa
```

Explanation: `-p` and `-e` means work like `sed`, `-0777` means shove whole file as single line. `s/` - substitute, `/s` - make `.` also match newline character, I match `line_3` and non-greedily any characters before `aaa\n` and replace all of that with what I matched before `aaa\n` denoted by `(` and `)` followed by `YES REPLACE THIS\n`.

*(tested in perl 5.30.0)*

Comment: Avoid needless capture with `\K`: `s/line_3.*?\Kaaa\n//s`

Comment: And handle all such instances in the whole file, with `/g` (added, so `/sg`)

Comment: @zdim fixed, now `YES REPLACE THIS` is place where first `aaa` after `line3` is

Answer (score 2):

This was proposed (by the currently-accepted answer):

```bash
perl -pe'$f = 1 if /^line_3$/; if ($f) { $f = 0 if s/^aaa$/YES REPLACE THIS/ };'
```

It simplifies to this:

```bash
perl -pe'$f ||= /^line_3$/; $f &&= !s/^aaa$/YES REPLACE THIS/;'
```

But the flip-flop operator does a lot of that work for us!

```bash
perl -pe'/^line_3$/ .. s/^aaa$/YES REPLACE THIS/'
```

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is good for automated **ed**iting of files:

```bash
ed -s file.txt <<<EOF
/line_3/;/aaa/,.c
YES REPLACE THIS
.
w
EOF
```

Finds the first line matching `line_3`, then **c**hanges the first line after that matching `aaa`, and finally **w**rites the modified file back out.