# Select multiple lines from a file and save it to a new file using perl

Tags: perl, search

i have a file from which i have to grep multiple lines between two specific string and save it to a new file as it is ..

The file is as below:

```
module abc (
abc,
efg,
..
..
 );
core M1 sj
corem m2
apple 
......
```

the starting string is module and last string is ");" . The desired output is as below:

```
module abc (
abc,
efg,
..
..
 );
```

below is the script which i had tried :

```
open(my $fh, "<", "test.v")
or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
my $original = <$fh>;
close($fh);

open(INFILE, ">", "result.v")
my $abc = $original =~ /module .*\)\;/ ;   //selecting string from module to ");" 
print INFILE $abc;
close(INFILE);
```

Kindly help me with a perl script .

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

```bash
perl -ne'print if /^module/ .. /^\s*\);/'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

Comment: Thank you for your response . But could you also suggest a command which i can use inside a perl script to get the same result ..

Comment: `-ne'...'` is equivalent to `while (<>) { ... }`