# Matching a number after a tab as one single line

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to know how to extract all the numbers after the ID (KC000001-3), including the number set after a tap using Perl regex.

The additional number (0.50) for the first ID, (0.60) second ID, and (0.70 0.80) third ID is always starting with a space as a new line and ending up with another tap.

Input file.

```
KC000001    0.30    0.40    0.50
KC000002    0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60
KC152363    0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60    0.70    0.80
```

I would like to get this output file.

```
0.30    0.40    0.50
0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60
0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60    0.70    0.80
```

I have prepared this regex.

```
if ($linea =~ /^(.[a-z0-9]\d+.\d)\s(.?)$/){
    print $line 
}
```

However, it is giving me the following error (it is not printing the number after the tab (0.50 for the first), (0.60 for the second), and (0.70 0.80 for the third))

```
0.30    0.40
0.30    0.40    0.50
0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60
```

I would like to know what is wrong with this regex. Is it possible to make it with a regex only?

Input file.

```
KC000001    0.30    0.40    0.50
KC000002    0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60
KC152363    0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60    0.70    0.80
```

Output file

```
0.30    0.40
0.30    0.40    0.50
0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60
```

Comment: What is a "tap"? Are those all typos for "tab"?

Comment: What is the contents of `$line` and `$linea`?

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: That regex would not match that line. You can't have tried this code, or you are doing something else which is printing what you see.

Answer (score 3):

With a Perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -F"\t" -nE 'say join "\t", @F[1..$#F]' file | tee output_file
0.30    0.40    0.50
0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60
0.30    0.40    0.50    0.60    0.70    0.80
```

This is an [*array slice*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol#Slices) operation, to retain only *column-2-till-the-end*.

Comment: You've lost the spaces between each field.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{^KC\w+\t}{}' infile > outfile
```

or change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{^KC\w+\t}{}' infile
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 1):

This removes everything up to and including the first tab of each line:

```perl
$line =~ s/^[^\t]*\t//;
print $line;
```

---

As a one-liner:

```bash
perl -pe's/^[^\t]*\t//'
```

See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924).