# bash command to replace all occurrences in a file with null bytes

Tags: bash, file, sh

Suppose there is a file named `example_file`, let's assume it's binary.

I want to replace all occurrences of the string `example_str` in it with the corresponding sequence of null bytes (`\0`), so that each character in the occurrence is replaced by a null byte. (explicitly specifying `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0` is not an option because (1) it's inconvenient, (2) I would like to use this command multiple times for different strings)

Is there a `bash` command to achieve this? I'd prefer it to be as concise and straightforward as possible.

Comment: does the file fit comfortably in ram? if not, is it guaranteed that nuls appear often enough that any string between two nuls fits comfortably in memory?

Comment: Does [Patching a binary with `dd`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214824/266568) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -- -s=example_str
```

Notes:

- This loads the entire file into memory.
- This works for any substring. It can contain any "special" character except NULs since they can't be passed a parameters. You'd have to hardcode the pattern if you want to pass NULs,

  ```bash
  perl -0777pe'
     BEGIN {
        $s = "\0\1\2\0\1\2";
        $r = "\0" x length($s);
     }
     s/\Q$s/$r/g;
  '
  ```

  or use some form of encoding.

  ```bash
  perl -0777spe'
     BEGIN {
        $s = pack "H*", $s;
        $r = "\0" x length($s);
     }
     s/\Q$s/$r/g;
  ' -- -s=000102000102   # Hex
  ```
- See [Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924). Any use of `-i` would have to be placed before the `--`.

Example

```
$ printf 'fooqwebar\n' >file

$ perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s=qwe file

$ cat -vT file
foo^@^@^@bar
```

Comment: 1) I can't figure out how to specify the file in this command. Can you show an example of its usage? 2) The substring can contain any characters? Can you provide an example using the string "\0\1\2\0\1\2"?

Comment: 1) See link I already provided in answer. Basic case: `perl ... infile >outfile` 2) I presume you mean the 6 chars 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2. Unfortunately, char 0 can't be passed as an argument. You'd have to hardcode that command (`perl -0777pe'BEGIN { $s = "\0\1\2\0\1\2"; $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g'`) or something.

Comment: I'm trying to run `perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i example_file -- -s example_str`, but it interprets `--`, `-s`, and `example_str` as files and messages, that there is not such file or directory.

Comment: I tries `perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s "qwe" example_file`, but it still recognizes qwe as a file name. I tried `perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s"qwe" example_file` - and it doesn't print any errors, but doesn't do anything either. Also setting the `s` variable inside the `'BEGIN { $s=... }` works.

Comment: My bad. The syntax is `-s=val` (Needs a `=`.) Fixed answer.

Comment: Thank you! Your command fits the requirements perfectly! Also my answer isn't that bad too :) But your is better.

Comment: "It can contain any "special" character. Except NULs" - I tried to execute `perl -0777spe'BEGIN{$r="\0"x length($s)}s/\Q$s/$r/g' -i -- -s="\1\1\2\2" example_file`, but it didn't work. Defining the `s` variable inside the code works. So it looks like not all special characters are allowed.

Comment: You didn't pass character 1, you passed the character `\ ` followed by the character `1`. If you want to replace character 1, you need to pass character 1.

Comment: I tried to pass the character with byte value 1 ('\1'), not the character, that represents number 1 ('1').

Comment: If you had, it would have worked. `perl -0777spe'BEGIN { $r = "\0" x length($s) } s/\Q$s/$r/g' -- -s="$( printf '\1' )" <( printf 'abc\1def\n' )  | od -t c` (And you can verify that `printf '\1'` does the right thing using `printf '\1' | od -t x1`)

Comment: The naive `-s="\1"` doesn't work. `-s="$( printf '\1' )"` works. Thank you.

Comment: Re "*The naive `-s="\1"` doesn't work.*", Only in the sense that you asked it to replace `foo` when you want it to replace `bar`.  `-s="\1"` does exactly what I said it does: It replaces `\ ` followed by `1` with two NULs.

Comment: Yeah, this is another case. I was talking about the special character '\1'. Not about the character '\' followed by the character '1'.

Comment: But I already explained that `\1` is two characters, neither of which are character with value 1. You need to pass the character you want to replace, not completely different characters.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
$ repl=foo
$ zero=$( printf '%s' "$repl" | sed 's/./\\x00/g' )
$ echo "$zero"
\x00\x00\x00
$ printf 'foo\0foo\0' | sed "s/$repl/$zero/g" | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
00000008
```

NOTE: You may need to do some escaping work to make `sed` happy if there are some special chars (like `/`) in the string you want to replace.

Comment: Or simply: `sed -e "s/$repl/${repl//?/\\o0}/"`, under [tag:bash].

Comment: The solution in the answer and the one in the comments both fail if `repl` contains certain characters.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

```
python -c "n='example_file';r=b'example_str';f=open(n,'r+b');d=f.read().replace(r,b'\0'*len(r));f.seek(0);f.write(d)"
```

Here is the same code but in a more readable form:

```
file_name = 'example_file'
to_replace = b'example_str'
f = open(file_name, 'r+b')
data = f.read().replace(to_replace, b'\0' * len(to_replace))
f.seek(0)
f.write(data)
```

Since the file is binary, the `b` symbol is used before the string `example_str`. This may not be necessary if a `unicode` string meets the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Many text processing tools won't allow you to use NUL byte in their code since they're implementerd in C where NUL represents the end of a string and so cannot be present within a string, but using GNU awk which does allow NUL bytes and processing of binary files:

```
$ awk -v BINMODE=3 -v old='example_str' '
    BEGIN { new = gensub(/./,"\0","g",old) }
    { print gensub(old,new,"g") }
' example_file | cat -A
I want to replace all occurrences of the string ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ in it with the corresponding sequence of null bytes$
```

The `| cat -A` is just so you can see the NUL bytes as `^@`s in the output.

The above assumes your old string does not contain any regexp metachars.

Answer (score 1):

In [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

Contents of `obli.tl`:

```
(match (@file @pattern) *args*
  (let* ((rx (regex-compile pattern))
         (str (file-get-string file))
         (pos (rra rx str)))
    (each ((range pos))
      (let* ((substr [str range])
             (u8len (coded-length substr))
             (blank (str u8len #\pnul)))
        (set [str range] blank)))
    (if pos
      (file-put-string `@file.blanked` str))))
```

Shorter version, using `regsub`:

```
(match (@file @pattern) *args*
  (flow file
    file-get-string
    (regsub (regex-compile pattern)
            [chain coded-length (lop str #\pnul)])
    (file-put-string `@file.blanked`)))
```

Example run: we make a local copy of `/bin/ls` and filter it to `ls.blanked` with the above program, where `invalid` is replaced by null bytes:

```
$ cp /bin/ls ls
$ txr obli.tl ls invalid
```

We can see the two files are of the same size:

```
$ ls -l ls*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 kaz kaz 145144 Dec 31 10:15 ls
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kaz kaz 145144 Dec 31 10:15 ls.blanked
```

Using `strings`, process substitution and `diff`, we can see the obliteration of `invalid`:

```
$ diff -u <(strings ls) <(strings ls.blanked)
--- /dev/fd/63  2023-12-31 10:15:34.281477192 -0800
+++ /dev/fd/62  2023-12-31 10:15:34.281477192 -0800
@@ -1050,9 +1050,9 @@
 QUOTING_STYLE
 COLUMNS
 TABSIZE
-invalid line width
+ line width
 %s: %s
-invalid tab size
+ tab size
 --sort
 --time
 --format
@@ -1065,7 +1065,7 @@
 LS_BLOCK_SIZE
 *=>@|
 TIME_STYLE
-invalid time style format %s
+ time style format %s
 time style
 Valid arguments are:
   - [posix-]%s
[... more hunks snipped ...]
```

The altered program executes:

```
$ chmod a+x ls.blanked
$ ./ls.blanked
ls  ls.blanked  obli.tl
```

Notes: in this program we assume that the regex match can be arbitrary: it doesn't match just a fixed string. Therefore, the number of bytes that need to be obliterated must be determined for each match. The match ranges are measured in Unicode codepoints, since all strings are represented that way. Our replacement text, however, must be a number of null bytes whose length is equal to the UTF-8 representation. So we construct a string of nulls whose length is the `coded-len` of the matching substring, and replace each match with that.

TXR's UTF-8 machinery is such that arbitrary binary files can be read as strings, and recovered to the exact byte format. All bytes of the binary which are invalid UTF-8 are decoded into the code point range U+DCxx. Any null byte in the data becomes U+DC00, which is called "pseudo-null" in TXR. That U+DC00 character has a representation in the TXR Lisp syntax as `#\pnul`, which makes an appearance in the above program. When string data is output into a stream, these U+DCxx codes are converted back to the bytes they represent. Our U+DC00 pseudo-nulls become null bytes.