# perl one-liner to change : to / and / to : in single line

Tags: perl, one-liner

Is there a perl one-liner to change ":" to "/" and  "/" to ":" in every line of a file.

for example:

```
fffc002/fffc002:9090 
fffc003/fffc003:9090 
fffc004/fffc004:9090
```

above thing should be changed to

```
fffc002:fffc002/9090
fffc003:fffc003/9090 
fffc004:fffc004/9090
```

Comment: `tr '[:/]' '[/:]'`would do the job. And there might even exist a perl built-in for that. But it's long ago that I spoke that language

Comment: I don't do one-liners, but `tr '[:/]' '[/:]'` is not perl code.   `tr'/:':/'` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @TomWilliams `tr` is a [posix command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html). `tr :/ /:` is shorter than `perl -pe y=/:=:/=`

Comment: From [perolop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr): *tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr.  For sed devotees, `y` is provided as a synonym for `tr`.*  Therefore, in perl `y` and `tr` are the same operator.

Answer (score 4):

```bash
perl -pe'tr{:/}{/:}'
```

[Specifying file to process to Perl one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41742890/589924)

---

That said, you might have a `tr` command-line utility which could do the same.

```bash
tr :/ /:
```